# How to enable cookie based authentication with istio ingress

Tags: authentication, cookies, istio, nginx-ingress, envoyproxy

We are running jenkins and few other tools behind nginx ingress and we have handled the user authentication through this as well.
Once the user logs in to our app, the credentials get stored in nginx ingress and it is passed to jenkins as cookies. 
Hence once user gets redirected to jenkins from our app, he would be logged into jenkins automatically.

Now we are trying to replace nginx ingress with istio ingress. We have placed our application behind istio ingress and are using the OIDC provider-keycloak along with [authservice](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/tree/master/bookinfo-example) for authentication. 
We are able to get the user to login to our app. But we are trying to figure out a way in which we can pass these credentials onto jenkins using cookies or through any other means.

Can someone let us know a way in which this can be achieved?

Comment: Hi, AFAIK cookie propagation has to be done on application side. There is an old [issue](https://github.com/istio/old_issues_repo/issues/46) on github about this.

Comment: So as per this, Istio wont handle the sending of cookies to the application right? Can you please tell me if there are any docs on how to handle this from the application side? Thanks @PiotrMalec